# Input Button Using Sliding Doors CSS

Tags: css, forms, button, input, sliding

Designed specifically for input buttons such as `<input type="submit" value="Button Name">`, this round button style uses the [sliding doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) technique that's assembled from a single image.

Demo: [Click to review the source code and demo the code in action](http://jsbin.com/azuta5/)
Demo: [Click to see a video demo of the style in Mac browsers: Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera](http://screencast.com/t/qRBaUyFwa)

This button style enables the following:

- Resolves wide button issue for long
  button names for IE browsers.
- Resolves an issue with IE browsers when the right sliding door piece would float on the page when the button is hidden server side.
- Resolves fragmented text issue for IE browsers
  when scrolling down and then back up the page.
- This is the perfect alternative for
  designers when you **can't use** the ASP
  .Net button control such as
  `<asp:Button id="b1" Text="Submit"
  runat="server" />` in your code
- Cross compatible
  for safari, ie, firefox, chrome and
  opera. [watch video](http://screencast.com/t/qRBaUyFwa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to change one pseudo-class.

```
span.button input.form_button:hover {
  background-position:left -39px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Should be

```
span.button:hover input.form_button {
  background-position:left -39px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Edit: It's line 52 of the demo source

Comment: you solved it! Also, I added this based on your suggestion so when the right tip is clicked, it will active the left side properly too. Thank you Ryan! I now have a finished button!

span.button:active input.form_button {
  background-position:left -78px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}